# Clearing iframe content to allow re-load

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using IE

I have a jsp page with a simple form, and an iframe tag to feed the results back.

When I hit submit button, right before the form is submitted, I need to blank out the iframe content from previous loads if any.

```
<form name="Iamaform" action="<%=contextPath%>/Someservlet" id="Iamaform"  method="post" target="result">
```

some submit button on click calls refresh()

```
</form>
```

iframe:

```
<iframe id="result" name="result" src="blank.html" onload="bufferloaded()" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

js function:

```
    function Refresh()
    {
    var frm = document.Iamaform;
    var rDoc = document.frames('result').document;

    //I need to clear the iframe before every form submit
    if(rDoc.all('refreshResults') != null){
        rDoc.all('refreshResults') = null;  //this throws an error when i hit submit the second time
    }
    window.Response.innerHTML ='';
         frm.submit ( );
}

    function BufferLoaded()
    {

    var rDoc = document.frames('result').document;

    if( rDoc == null ||
        rDoc.all('refreshResults') == null ||
        (rDoc.all('refreshResults') + '') == 'undefined' )
        return false;

    if( rDoc.all('refreshResults').innerText == 'TIMEOUT' )
    {
        return false;
    }

    window.Response.innerHTML = rDoc.all('refreshResults').innerText;

        }
```

Comment: why you need to clear it ? it automatically refreshes when you load a new document in it

Comment: `document.all` and `document.frames` are arrays, not functions. You should use `document.frames['result']` rather than `document.frames('result')`; same for `document.all`. Actually, don't use `document.all` at all if you can avoid it. Use the standard `document.getElementsById()`;

Answer (score 0):

```
document.frames['result'].src = "about:blank";
```

This will clear the frame. But, I don't know why you would want to do this, because setting a frames `src` automatically clears the frame before loading a new page.